# Connecting to mysql cluster from python application

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-cluster

I have configured the server to use MySQL Cluster. The Cluster architecture is as follows:

One Cluster Manager(ip1)

Two Data Nodes (ip2,ip3)

Two SQL Nodes(ip4,ip5)

My Question: Which node should I use to connect from Python application?

Comment: Ask your database admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call SQL nodes from your application. Use comma separated ip addresses for this. In your code use
DB_HOST = "ip4, ip5"